# Alternative to FIRST_VALUE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'd like to run this query:

```
;WITH ToUpdate AS (
   SELECT Id1, Id2,
          FIRST_VALUE(Id1) OVER (PARTITION BY Id2 ORDER BY Id1) AS newValue
   FROM mytable
)
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET Id2 = newValue
```

But FIRST_VALUE isn't available in SQL Server 2008, is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : Using OUTER APPLY

```
;WITH ToUpdate AS (
      SELECT Id1, Id2,
      M.newValue AS newValue
      FROM mytable t1
      OUTER APPLY(
         SELECT top 1 t2.ID1 AS newValue
         FROM mytable t2 WHERE t1.Id2=t2.Id2
         ORDER BY t2.ID1
      )M   
)
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET Id2 = newValue
```